# Pythonとラズパイで簡単な防犯システムを作っているが、うまく動かない。

Tags: python, python3

Pythonとラズベリーパイで、防犯システムを作っているんですが、赤外線センサで感知すると、ラズパイに信号が送られ、一回感知すると音声1が流れ、二回感知すると音声2が流れ、三回感知すると音声3が流れ、四回感知すると音声4が流れ、音声4が流れると、次反応した時、音声1から流れるというシステムです。

なのになぜか、一回センサが反応すると、一気に音声2,3,4が流れてしまいます。何もセンサにかざしてないのに、勝手に音声が流れます。どこかプログラムがおかしいでしょうか。見てください！お願いします！

```
try:     
    while True:
        flag = GPIO.input(PIN_IN) == GPIO.HIGH //信号を受け取る部分
        if (flag == True) and (sensor_count==0):　//一回感知した場合
            Play_warning_voice1()
            sensor_count = sensor_count + 1

        elif (flag == True) and (sensor_count==1): //二回感知した場合
            Play_warning_voice2()
            sensor_count = sensor_count + 1

        elif (flag == True) and (sensor_count==2)://三回感知した場合 
            Play_warning_voice3()
            sensor_count = sensor_count + 1   

        elif (flag == True) and (sensor_count>=3):  //四回感知した場合 
            Play_warning_voice4()
            sensor_count = 0

        else:
            pass    

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: ある回と次の回の`flag = GPIO.input(PIN_IN) == GPIO.HIGH //信号を受け取る部分`が呼ばれる時間間隔の調整とか、チャタリング防止とか、短時間で実際に信号が変化した場合をどう判断するか、長時間検出したままの場合にどう対処するか等々、といった色々な発生し得る条件に対する場合分けや対処が考えられていないように見えます。単純に間隔を空けずにループして1舜の間に4回まわってしまったのでは? あとは赤外線センサがどんな機能を持っていてどういう条件でどういう通知が発生するか等の仕様を示す情報や資料が必要ですね。

Comment: こちらでは活発に応対されているようですが。[Pythonとラズパイで簡単な防犯システムを作っているが、うまく動かない。](https://teratail.com/questions/349849)